# POST form with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to post this form with jquery/ajax instead of with the form action url. I've written what I think would work, but I'm getting an error, `error: Shell form does not validate`.

Any help to get this working?

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/motioncrafter/ot8ft89y/1/) with form working with a form `action=url`.

And here's what I've done to submit this form via AJAX, but I'm getting an error that is telling me to use a POST request.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div>Enter Filename</div>
    <input id="filename" type="text" name="entry.944320400">
    <div>Enter Name</div>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="entry.2146460057">
    <br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1P6iosp_9AoYA1Rcn86T8j8_6xHdKp5KCKmEexMiDTsA/formResponse";
    var data = $('form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function () {
            alert("Success");

        }
    });
```

Comment: try `<input id="submit" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">`

Comment: The form is being posted to the server as well as by your Ajax post. You need to add a e.preventDefault(); statement to stop the form being posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting via the form tag that has a default method of GET

Try:

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
        var url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1P6iosp_9AoYA1Rcn86T8j8_6xHdKp5KCKmEexMiDTsA/formResponse";
        var data = $('form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function () {
                alert("Success");

            }
        });
```

Comment: That makes sense-- here it is in a fiddle, but still not working. http://jsfiddle.net/motioncrafter/8r4dqgj1/ and the doc is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nm1RlDd09ZiTm4u7z0Zv5twwrutnSUFyWi2hGBWPlPY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: its not working because google doesn't allow it `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`

Comment: Damn. Thanks! I guess I'll have to put it in an iframe so it doesn't redirect upon form submittal.

Comment: the only whey i know is to hack it and insert a hidden iframe of google page, than you pass the data from your site to the hidden google iframe and you submit the iframe button

Answer (score 0):

The form is being posted to the server as well as by your Ajax post. You need to add a e.preventDefault(); statement to stop the form being posted.

Ooops, I added this as a comment instead of as an answer!